# A dynamic size array in C

Tags: c

I have encountered with interesting situation when initializing dynamic size variables.

For example:

```
// getInput() is some magic method to retrieve input with dynamic length string
// some times it can be 10, some times 99 and so on
char vector[strlen(getInput())] = getInput();
```

In this case definitely wont work since compiler can't allocate some fixed size memory to heap, that's right?

But in this case, it works fine:

```
char path[] = "";
strcpy(path, getInput());
```

Why it doesn't work in first case and works in second? Is maybe `strcpy` uses `malloc` or something?

Comment: The second case doesn't work either. It will result in buffer overflow.

Comment: This is very "bad practice". Use `malloc` and go ahead.

Comment: The first case doesn't work because the initializer for a char array must either be a `char`, or a string literal , or those in braces, or a brace-enclosed list of `char`.  The return value of `getInput` is none of those.

Comment: It would help if you show an outline of what `getInput` does, and how it allocates memory and returns. For example, even if you fix up your first line of code, you call the function twice (so it might read the input twice, depending on how you implemented it).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `char vector[strlen(getInput())] = getInput();`

Calling the getInput() function twice in the same expression doesn't make any sense. In particular, you don't copy strings with the `=` operator but with `strcpy()`. Also, you need to allocate space for the null terminator.

Assuming these are *local* variables (they should be), what you should do instead is this:

```
int main (void)
{
  const char* input = getInput();
  char vector[strlen(input) + 1];
  strcpy(vector, input);
  ...
}
```

---

> But in this case, it works fine:
>
> `char path[] = "";`
> `strcpy(path, getInput());`

No, it doesn't work fine! All you did was do declare a static array of size 1 (size of the null terminator), then you copy data of longer length into that array. This causes an array out of bounds bug which is *undefined behavior*, anything can happen. Unfortunately, it caused your program to seem to work ok, while it actually has a latent severe bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
char vector[strlen(getInput())] = getInput();
```

You are mixing a char array initialization expected by `char vector[strlen(getInput())] =` with the assignment of a array pointer returned by `getInput()`.

**Possible Solutions**

You can either initialize the array with values

```
char vector[strlen(getInput())] = { 'a', 'b', .. 'z' };
```

Or obtain the array pointer returned by `getInput`

```
const char * vector = getInput();
```

Or copy the array returned by `getInput` into vector array

```
const char * input = getInput();
const size_t size = strlen(input);
char vector [size+1] = { 0 };
memset(vector , '\0', sizeof(vector));
strcpy(vector,input);
```

Comment: You need to allocate room for the null terminator.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the function *getInput* returns a character pointer, so you cannot assign the result to an array. Also in

```
char path[] = "";
```

the length of *path* is only one character (the null character), so copying the input to this variable is only valid if the input is the empty string.

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NEW_ARRAY(ptr, n) \
    { \
        (ptr) = malloc((n) * sizeof (ptr)[0]); \
        if ((ptr) == NULL) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "error: Memory exhausted\n"); \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
        } \
    }

const char *getInput(void);

int main(void)
{
    const char *input;
    char *inputCopy;
    int inputLength;

    input = getInput();
    inputLength = strlen(input);
    NEW_ARRAY(inputCopy, inputLength + 1);
    strcpy(inputCopy, input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid writing macros like these for type safety reasons. If you for some reason need a wrapper around `malloc`, then write a function with the same signature as malloc. It is usually not a good idea to localize error handling anyhow.

Comment: @Lundin The reason for introducing the macro is because *malloc* is error prone; when you call *malloc* you need to provide the type of the variable or the designator. If you call *NEW_ARRAY* with wrong arguments you will get a compilation error so in practice it is type-safe (and also easier to read than a *malloc* assignment.